# error while writing media query

Tags: html, css, scala, playframework

I am using `Scala` and `playFramework` in my project and i have some problem while writing a media query in my `html` page.

Here is my code

```
@(mailContent: String)
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Mail template</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <style>
        .img-brand {
            margin-left:20px; width:40%; height:40%;
        }
        .date { 
            font-size:125%; color:#5d5d5d; float:right; margin-right:20px; margin-top:55px;
        }
        @media (max-width:480px){
            .img-brand { margin-left:10px; width:90%; height:90%;}
            .date { font-size:125%; color:#5d5d5d; float:right; margin-right:20px; margin-top:10px;}
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

If u see we are using `@` to create some variables so if i write some query like that media it is giving me the error

Can some one help me how to write a media query without using `@`

I thought `media Query` is the only problem and it got resolved by adding `@@` but now i found that `style` itself is not getting used or called.
So, can somebody help me on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape the `@` character: it is used by Play templates. So when you write `@media`, Play tries to find a variable named `media`, which will probably fail. To escape use `@@`:

```
@(mailContent: String)
<p>Hi</p>
<style>
@@media (max-width:480px){
    // (...)
}
</style>
```

Note two things:

- You won't have this problem if you place your code in a .css file apart and add a link in the html (Play wont process it)
- Probably your IDE will complain that `@@` is not valid CSS. After Play processes it `@@media` becomes `@media`, so you can just ignore it.

Comment: By the way i have got one more problem. I thought media query is causing problem but the style itself is not getting recognized. I removed the media query but still the style is not getting recognized can u help me in that and thanks for the above answer

Comment: @raja Update your question with the problems you have now. If it is something completely different than the original question it may be better to ask a new question...